# SharePoint Query Content Class for Pages?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, caml-query

I am trying to build a query to filter only returning a specific section of new pages using Content Class.

I am wondering what is the content class for pages? I know for List Item, I could do {ContentClass:sts_listitem}, not sure what it is for pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use STS_List_850, which is the pages list.

If that does not work you can filter on other properties.

It is easy to filter on ContentType if you can separate the news on ContentType.

If they all share the same ContentType you can add another column to your ContentType, for example "PageScope" and set the value of the column to Global or Local depending on where in you want the page to show up. Then you need to add a Managed property in Search administraion from the crawled property. It will take a while for the new column to show up as a crawled property. You can then filter on the Managed property and only get the articles you want.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but doesn't work. Once I added the {contentclass:STS_List_850} into the query, nothing is returned. I checked all these pages are under Site Contents->Pages folder.

Comment: Did you try any of the other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I tried a few different other options as well, doesn't work either. So not sure where it goes wrong.

Comment: @XiaoHan does the new column show up i  the list of crawled properties? If not make sure or wait for crawling to run.

Comment: My query is like {contentclass:sts_listitem}
path:http://testportal/en-us/news/Pages/, it does not return anything,but I expect to return the pages in the document library. I didn't create any new column, just a test page. I believe all the properties should have been crawled?